# Unable to loop the api data in angular

Tags: angular

I have API response as below.
[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tzp4.png)
API :
{
"isSuccess": true,
"message": "Data fetched successfully",
"data": [
{
"id": "62fed72c775efbb8b1746587",
"createdDate": "19-08-2022 05:49:56",
"updatedDate": "",
"firstName": "Harika",
"lastName": "Ramesh",
"age": 27,
"contact": "987t65767",
"salary": 150000,
"message": null
},
{
"id": "62fed8b3c601d740feea86c7",
"createdDate": "19-08-2022 05:56:18",
"updatedDate": "",
"firstName": "Hari",
"lastName": "Kesh",
"age": 28,
"contact": "456789900",
"salary": 987654,
"message": null
},
{
"id": "62fedb5c05399d26b492f42e",
"createdDate": "19-08-2022 06:07:44",
"updatedDate": "",
"firstName": "Ram",
"lastName": "D",
"age": 29,
"contact": "9876543",
"salary": 1500000,
"message": null
}
]
}

But in angular return response how to pass only array data that i can loop I am not sure since I am new to angular.
Following are some code

```
crudOp.model.ts file
export interface crudOp {
    Id:string;
    CreatedDate:string;
    UpdatedDate:string;
    FirstName:string;
    LastName:string;
    Age:number;
    Contact:number;
    Salary:number;
    Message:string;
}



crud-mongo.service.ts
export class CrudMongoService { 
  baseUrl = "https://localhost:44391/api/CrudOperations";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  GetAllRecord(): Observable<crudOp[]>{
    return this.http.get<crudOp[]>(this.baseUrl + '/GetAllRecord');

  }
}



app.component.ts file 
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'CrudMongo';
  crudlist:crudOp[] =[];

  constructor(private crudMongoService :CrudMongoService){

  }
  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.GetAllRecord();
  }

  GetAllRecord(){
    this.crudMongoService.GetAllRecord()
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        // console.log(Object.values(response)[2]);
        console.log(response);
        this.crudlist = response;
      });
  }
}
```

I want to loop the "data" array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you just need to check does the response have data or not and assign data to your array. below I modified **GetAllRecord** method.

### app.component.ts file

```js
 GetAllRecord(){
    this.crudMongoService.GetAllRecord()
    .subscribe(response: any => {
        console.log(response);
        this.crudlist = response && response.data ? response.data : [];
     });
  }
```

Changed the return type in the service file, because API not returning the type of data that you mentioned for the service method. edited your code.

```js
export class CrudMongoService { 
  baseUrl = "https://localhost:44391/api/CrudOperations";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  GetAllRecord() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/GetAllRecord');

  }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to use response.data it gives me error like : https://prnt.sc/AkPc959hvGuy

Error: src/app/app.component.ts:26:62 - error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'crudOp[]'.

Comment: because you mentioned the return type for the method in the service file. I used return type as any, if you don't want to use any as return type need to change the service method.

Comment: In console still I get an error not sure why
https://prnt.sc/I5m20rQmzJlh

Comment: remove that any also and try again. remove complete <any> in both places

Comment: Still getting error:
https://prnt.sc/0-_3M9r5yEcD

Comment: Edited answer, try as per answer and let me know

Comment: Not working yet : https://prnt.sc/qyPnNZooHm6R

Comment: is it working by removing `any` after response in component file

Comment: Console i get 
Observable<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'crudOp[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 27 more.

Comment: did you change your service method as per the answer

Comment: Inside app.component.ts subscription of GetAllRecords function to check nullable of response we can do 
this.crudList = response?.data || []